# How to prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a_{n}}{r_{n}^{p}}>>\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ when the latter is convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}\left(a_{n}>0\right)$ be a convergent series, $r_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} a_{k}$, $b_{n}=\dfrac{a_{n}}{r_{n}^{p}}$ with $0<p<1$. I want to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ is finite but much bigger than $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$.

The convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ is easier to prove: $$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} b_{k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{r_k-r_{k+1}}{r_k^p}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\int_{r_{k+1}}^{r_k}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{r_k^p}<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\int_{r_{k+1}}^{r_k}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{x^p}=\int_{r_{n+1}}^{r_1}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{x^p}<\infty.
$$
However, I have no idea about how to estimate the difference between $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.